# Where can I find replacement tips for the 5-way switch on my Squier Stratocaster?

Tags: electric-guitar

I own a Squier Vintage Modified '70s Stratocaster (it's made in Indonesia, if that helps), and I'm having trouble finding replacement tips for the 5-way switch.  I ordered a set of "White Switch Knobs for Import Stratocaster" made by AllParts, but they don't fit.  So, where can I find a set of replacement tips that will fit?

Comment: In what way won't it fit? Too big/small?

Answer (score 1):

Fender has a parts department. It might be a good idea to give them a call. You might need to have the serial number for the guitar handy.

Comment: That's probably my best bet!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll do that and then let you know how it goes.